# How to find a specific value with Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need to get only values for "since", instead I get all values with the same name of class.

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/scottish-premiership/verletztespieler/wettbewerb/SC1/plus/1");
foreach ($html->find('.zentriert') as $element){
    echo $element->plaintext ."\n";
}
```

---

**Result after running the code**

> Club Age Nation since until
>
> 28
>
> Dec 27, 2016 Feb 24, 2017
>
> 33
>
> Dec 24, 2016 Feb 28, 2017
>
> 25
>
> Jan 31, 2017 Feb 28, 2017
>
> 19
>
> ....

---

### I need to retrieve only the data from the column I selected.

[image]

I used this code to get the names for players i want to do the same for the column SINCE

```
foreach ($html->find('.hauptlink') as $element) {
    $player_name = trim($element->plaintext);
    echo $player_name ."\n";
}
```

---

### The sum of what i need to achieve is to get the player name, nation, injury, since and until values for earch row.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding by class, find it by the column index.

```
foreach ($html->find('.items td:nth-child(6)') as $element){
    echo $element->plaintext ."\n";
}
```

Comment: If there is only one item found, the foreach is unnecessary and you could just access  using `$html->find('.items td:nth-child(6)',0)->plaintext`

Comment: @Theo I thought he wants the `Since` column in every row.

Comment: The problem he's having is that both `Since` and `To` have the class `.zentriert`.

Comment: the question says "I need to retrieve only the data from the row i selected."

Comment: The first line says **I need to get only values for "since"**. I guess we need him to clarify. This wouldn't be the first time I've seen a foreigner
 get confused between row and column.

Comment: It was the column not the row sorry. I updated the question and i posted the second code i use to get the names. @Barmar your code doesn't output only the selected column it outputs the entire table.

Comment: Is there really a version of simple-html-dom where `nth-child(6)` works?

Comment: @pguardiario I didn't check, I assumed it would support most CSS selectors.

Comment: That's what I thought. It barely supports any in fact. [This one](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) does though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tdElements = $html->find('.items td.links+td.zentriert');
foreach($tdElements as $td){
    echo $element->plaintext ."\n";
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, but now with the clarification you want several rows it only differs slightly from @Barmars answer which I have now upvoted. The difference is that he is looking for the 6th td in each row, whereas I am looking for a td with a class of `zentriert` that directly follows a td of with a class of `links` - this maybe slightly less likely to break if the table structure changes; but otherwise a fairly meaningless difference in this instance.